# Clustergram on Matlab - getting associated statistics

Tags: statistics

I have been using the clustergram feature in Matlab on my data in the following way;

```
Cobj2 = clustergram(c,'RowLabels',[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40],'ColumnLabels',{'Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4','Value5','Value6'},'Colormap',redbluecmap,'Standardize',1)
```

Matlab sorts my data into clusters and although I have found the dendogram and heatmap informative I would like to find out a little more information about my clusters for example the euclidean distances between them or some other measure so I can determine their 'strength'. Is there a way to get more information or statistics about my graph?